# Table join to find a missing record?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, relational-database

[image: Image of tables]

How would I structure a query to join these two tables in a way that would return the highlighted record.  I want to return records where there is no record on the User/Group table that associates the user and group on a ticket.

Thanks!

Comment: Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite your textbook with a bespoke tutorial & do your (home)work & you have shown no research or other effort.  Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts.  Show what relevant parts you can do & ask 1 specific question re the first place you are stuck. Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted.

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an anti left join:

```
select t.*
from tickets
left join user_groups g
    on g.user = t.assigned_to
    and g.group = t.assigned_group
where g.user is null
```

You can also express this with `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from tickets t
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from user_group g
    where
        g.user = t.assigned_to
        and g.group = t.assigned_group
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
 SELECT * 
FROM   tickets t 
       LEFT JOIN USER u 
              ON ( t.USER = u.USER 
                   AND t.group = u.group 
                   AND u.USER IS NULL )
```

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty much the definition of an "anti-join":

```
select t.*
from tickets t
left join usergroup u on u.user = t.assignedto
where u.user is null
```

Comment: How can an inner join return the null when there are records in both the tables for minimal keys. Where u.user is null is pointless i guess in case of inner join replace it with left join. The sql executes in order as join first then where. So, after join there would not be any matching where coz the join will give matched ids only

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja My bad, I forgot it was supposed to be a left outer join. Fixed now.

Comment: Ok @TheImpaler.